# mobile chrome browser error: web socket connection failed : establishing a tunnel via proxy server failed

Tags: javascript, android, html, websocket, mobile-chrome

we are using plain **java script** for creating websocket client and connecting to websocket server(superwebsocket)

we are trying to connect and work on web sockets in some pages of our android app(on 4.4 version). when i try to open the page which is having web socket connections it is throwing the following error 'Websocket connection to 'ws://machinename:9013' failed: Establishing a tunnel via proxy server failed'

here are my observations:

1. Through emulator, successfully connecting to web socket
2. From mobile Mozilla browser, successfully connecting to web socket
3. From Chrome (android app opens url's in chrome mobile version) throwing an error 'connection failed while establishing a tunnel via proxy server failed' while connecting to web socket.
4. if the mobile is having old version of chrome i.e 41.0, web socket connections are successful but if chrome version is more than 41.0, it is throwing above mentioned error. now the latest chrome version is 43.

can you give some suggestions how to proceed further..are there any new changes in mobile chrome causing this issue?